# App that keeps track of what music files I listen fully / partially / skip

Tags: windows-7, music

I'm looking for an application that can keep track of music that I listen to, and show:

- Files that I like to hear more often than others (listen count)
- Files that I skip (bad track in playlist)
- Files that I rarely listen to (not skip, but simply don't load)

This could be useful to determine which tracks I like most, which tracks I don't like, and the tracks I haven't listened to yet. Is there such an application?

It would be great if I could keep using my favorite media player (MPC) and not be forced to use some other player just to make it work.

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: is [Last.Fm](http://www.last.fm)  an option? It can track how much you listen to a song (wich have to be played at least 50%), but it can't wich songs you skip.
You might also need this => http://mpcs.4fan.cz/

For example, this is my account => http://www.last.fm/user/diedie2

Answer (score 3):

**Scrobbling** is the term last.fm uses for keeping track of what songs you listen to either via its player or through software with a last.fm scrobbling plugin. So a search on scrobbling will give you lots more information on this subject.

More recently an open source scrobbling project has started called [ListenBrainz](https://listenbrainz.org) by the same people behind MusicBrainz  if you got in touch with them they would probably be interested in your ideas.